# Multidimensional scaling on distance or similarity matrix

Tags: distance, similarities, multidimensional-scaling, metric

Why doesn't the scatter plot change when I perform multidimensional scaling on distance or similarity matrix?

This figure uses similarity matrix

[image]

And this figure use distance matrix (sqrt(1-similarity))

[image]

Comment: This is because MDS software which converts similarities into dissimilarities do it other way than by formula sqrt(1-similarity). That formula - precisely, sqrt[2(1-similarity)] -- is best to convert Pearson correlation or cosine into euclidean distance, so it isn't universal.

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature!  :-).  Seriously, isn't this a desirable behavior?

Comment: @Dzung, you should consult your software documentation. MDS implementations vary in how they preprocess input proximity matrices, How and when they convert a similarity into a distance etc.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from comments:

That's not a bug, it's a feature! :-). Seriously, isn't this a desirable behavior? – Peter Flom   (which I wholeheartedly agree with)

For more details, you really need to consult your software's documentation. You didn't mention which software, and we cannot mindread.